# Can appending files lead to fragmentation?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, file, file-io

If we append to a file instead of updating a random access file which is faster.
I was wondering if we append to a file, won't we get fragmentation?
I read that databases e.g. MySQL appends the data in a log-based file first and then *eventually* saves the data to the actual "tables".

I was wondering if we append to a file and the file size changes, won't we have fragmentation and have the same issues as if we used writes in the random access file?

Comment: Fragmentation is not a problem within the file systems usually used inside linux systems. It is only a problem for file systems typically used in MS-Windows based systems.

Comment: As said by arkascha, Linux platform is already file-based but on a Windows platform, you tend to have both SQL file fragmentation and disk level fragmentation. For Microsoft SQL, the changes are first written to the log file and then committed to the database file during check-point

Comment: @arkascha:But when a file is created it occupies a space.Then the next file occupies some space.If the first file is constantly appended won't it get so large so as to reach the boundary of the second file and then need to assign blocks from another track?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover:I don't know what `file-based` means when describing the Linux platform (i.e. that it is file-based)

Comment: What you state is only true if the blocks are allocated in a sequential strategy. That is only the case in typical MS-Windows file systems. Other file systems use more intelligent strategies. It is a general observation that typical linux file systems have little to no issues with fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

(first, let's get this out of the way: file system level fragmentation is really an issue on Microsoft file systems only. Below comments regarding fragmentation apply to Microsoft files systems only, as the question is virtually irrelevant to Linux files systems)

You seem to be mixing two distinct mechanisms in MySQL:

### [The Binary Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log.html)

> The binary log contains "events" that describe database changes such as table creation operations or changes to table data.

It really is a log. It is written sequentially at the end of every transaction, and grows indefinitely as new transactions are committed. For completeness, let's mention that a new file is started over when the log reaches [`max_binlog_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_max_binlog_size), *à la* `logrotate`.

This file is subject to fragmentation as you describe it, because it grows constantly. But this fragmentation has little impact on performance, because it is not used intensively.

### [The Redo Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_redo_log)

> A disk-based data structure used during crash recovery, to correct data written by incomplete transactions. (...) Modifications that did not finish updating the data files before an unexpected shutdown are replayed automatically *[hence its name]*.

This log is more a buffer than a log. This log consists of a set of files of fixed size, allocated once on startup. Changes to the database are first written, sequentially, into this buffer zone, then transferred into the actual data files.

This buffer is not really subject to fragmentation, because its size is fixed. Fragmentation may always occur because of other factors, but should be minimal anyways.

---

PS: I would always avoid Windows as a host OS for MySQL in production. Performances on Windows are still a bit behind compared to Linux, anyways.

PPS: [Tables need defragmentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html), regardless of the underlying file system